# AS3 1 function to play different MovieClips from different buttons?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a couple of different buttons which all have corresponding MovieClips. 
e.g. the button is name "horse_btn" and the MovieClip "horse_btn_mc".

Now I need one function which plays the corresponding MovieCLip when the button is clicked. I tried this:

```
horse_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over);

function over(e:MouseEvent)
{
    var mc = e.currentTarget.name;
    mc += "_mc";
    mc.gotoAndPlay(1)
}
```

But I keep getting this error: 
TypeError: Error #1006: value is not a function.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type `String` dos not have a field `gotoAndPlay`. For get the display object you have to use "getChildBy...."-methods.

```
var theName = e.currentTarget.name + "_mc";
//var yourContainer:DisplayObjectContainer = e.currentTarget.parent as DisplayObjectContainer;
var mc:MovieClip = yourContainer.getChildByName( theName ) as MovieClip;
mc.gotoAndPlay(1);
```

See [doc: DisplayObjectContainer.getChildByName()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName()).

Comment: I was wondering if the string was be the problem!! Thank you so much! Works perfectly!

Comment: I have an additional question as well: I am trying to do the same thing with sounds but I can't get it to work. My sounds are in my library and I've checked "Export to AS3" and gave them a class name. How can I access them (same way I did with the MC's, by adding "_snd" to the target name)?

Comment: See `ApplicationDomain.getDefinitionBy..(your class id string)`. You'll get the Class object (what extends Sound). Next you can create its instance `var FooClass:Sound = getDefinitionByName("myFoo_snd"); var foo = new FooClass(); foo.play();`.                    I'm not about correct name of that method, sorry, because writing it from mind and on cellphone :)

Comment: Also see `yourRootDisplayObj.loaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition...`